# The :checked selector doesn't work beside working on the tutorial

Tags: html, css

I'm using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-pil5oHw0w), and beside some id/class name, I did exactly the same as the tutorial, but i still can't make the checked work.

I didn't get through the entire tutorial.
I tested both codes (code I tested with : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/)), but it looks like the problem isn't coming from the checkbox.

Here's the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
         <title>Test Sidebar</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <input type="checkbox" id="check">
         <header>
             <label for="check">
                <i class="fas fa-bars" id="sidebarBtn"></i>
             </label>
            <div class="leftArea">
                <h3>Side <span>Bar</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="rightArea">
                <a href="#" class="logoutBtn">Logout</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <center>
                    <img src="pic.jpg" class="profileImage" alt="">
                    <h4>Amanda</h4>
                </center>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i><span>Components</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-table"></i><span>Tables</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-th"></i><span>Forms</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><span>About</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i><span>Settings</span></a>
            </div>
         </header>
     </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    background: #22242A;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
.leftArea h3 {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.leftArea span {
    color: #1DC4E7;
}
.logoutBtn {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #19B3D3;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-property: background;
}
.logoutBtn:hover {
    background: #0D9DBB;
}

.sidebar {
    background: #2F323A;
    margin-top: 22px;
    /* margin-top: 70px - n'as pas l'air de fonctionner */
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%
}
.sidebar .profileImage {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar h4 {
    color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.sidebar a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-property: background;
}
.sidebar a:hover {
    background: #19B3D3;
}
.sidebar i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
label #sidebarBtn {
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-property: color;
}
label #sidebarBtn:hover {
    color: #19B3D3;
}

#check:checked ~ .sidebar {
    left: -190px;
}
```

Comment: Note, 'center' is an obsolete element and should no longer be used

Answer (score 1):

Place an `<input type="checkbox" id="check">` inside your `head` tag, but above the line `<label for="check">`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    background: #22242A;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
.leftArea h3 {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.leftArea span {
    color: #1DC4E7;
}
.logoutBtn {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #19B3D3;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-property: background;
}
.logoutBtn:hover {
    background: #0D9DBB;
}

.sidebar {
    background: #2F323A;
    margin-top: 22px;
    /* margin-top: 70px - n'as pas l'air de fonctionner */
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%
}
.sidebar .profileImage {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar h4 {
    color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.sidebar a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-property: background;
}
.sidebar a:hover {
    background: #19B3D3;
}
.sidebar i {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
label #sidebarBtn {
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 300px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transition-property: color;
}
label #sidebarBtn:hover {
    color: #19B3D3;
}

#check:checked ~ .sidebar {
    left: -190px;
}
```

```html
<body>
         
         <header>
         <input type="checkbox" id="check">
             <label for="check">
                <i class="fas fa-bars" id="sidebarBtn"></i>
             </label>
            <div class="leftArea">
                <h3>Side <span>Bar</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="rightArea">
                <a href="#" class="logoutBtn">Logout</a>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <center>
                    <img src="pic.jpg" class="profileImage" alt="">
                    <h4>Amanda</h4>
                </center>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i><span>Components</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-table"></i><span>Tables</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-th"></i><span>Forms</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><span>About</span></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i><span>Settings</span></a>
            </div>
         </header>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i just understood where i messed up. The  tag should close after the rightArea class.

```
         <header>
             <label for="check">
                <i class="fas fa-bars" id="sidebarBtn"></i>
             </label>
            <div class="leftArea">
                <h3>Side <span>Bar</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="rightArea">
                <a href="#" class="logoutBtn">Logout</a>
            </div>
         </header>
```

This way, i can have my input BEFORE my header, and it would works. I think it's because now, the sidebar isn't in the header anymore. That was pretty dumb on my part, sorry, and thank you for helping me out there.